# WiX: Install component based on ComboBox selection

Tags: combobox, wix, conditional-statements

I'm trying to create an installer which installs some components based on the selection of a Combobox but it seems like the condition isn't working. I declared the Combobox as the following:

```
...
<UI>
  <ComboBox Property="Option">
    <ListItem Text="Red" Value="red" />
    <ListItem Text="Blue" Value="blue" />
    <ListItem Text="Green" Value="green" />
  </ComboBox>
...
```

I have one Feature:

```
<Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="MyProgram" Level="1">
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
</Feature>
```

And the component Group is declared as the following:

```
<ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
  <Component Id="MainComponent">
    <File Id="exe" Name="Main.exe" Source="Main.exe" />
  </Component>
  <Component Id="ComponentRed">
    <Condition>Option=red</Condition>
    <File Id="R" Name="config.txt" Source="red.txt" />
  </Component>
  <Component Id="ComponentBlue">
    <File Id="B" Name="config.txt" Source="blue.txt" />
    <Condition>Option=blue</Condition>
  </Component>
  <Component Id="ComponentGreen">
    <File Id="G" Name="config.txt" Source="green.txt" />
    <Condition>Option=green</Condition>
  </Component>
</ComponentGroup>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property needs to be public (upper-case) and the comparison needs to be done inside a CDATA. You could use the case-insensitive comparison `~=`.

```
<Component Id="ComponentRed" Guid="*" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
    <File Id="R" Name="red.txt" Source="red.txt" />
    <Condition>
        <![CDATA[OPTION~="Red"]]>
    </Condition>
</Component>

<Control Id="MyComboBox" Type="ComboBox" X="20" Y="140" Width="56" Height="17"
         Property="OPTION">
    <ComboBox Property="OPTION">
        <ListItem Text="Red" Value="Red" />
        <ListItem Text="Blue" Value="Blue" />
        <ListItem Text="Green" Value="Green" />
    </ComboBox>
</Control>
```

Comment: This is the only way to get this this feature working.
Do not try to at the <condition> to the <Feature> itself. It will evaluate the expression early - before someone is able to select anything in the UI.